# How do I change the size of shadowCamera?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to update the width and height of the visibility of shadows from the light source, but I do not what comes out, no matter how much I did not twist something will not change

https://github-camo.global.ssl.fastly.net/7fb9f1127364d27f273ee4795f79bbcb7db1f54d/687474703a2f2f736c2d636d732e636f6d2f692f6b6f726e65722d323031332f326539303363383034303161323665336133313965353265346634622e706e67

```
if(object.shadowCameraLeft !== undefined) {
                methods.opValI(9,{name:'Sh Cam Left',value:object.shadowCameraLeft,step:10,fix:'2'},op,function(v){
                    object.shadowCameraLeft = v; // Trying to change
                });
            }

            if(object.shadowCameraRight !== undefined) {
                methods.opValI(9,{name:'Sh Cam Right',value:object.shadowCameraRight,step:10,fix:'2'},op,function(v){
                    object.shadowCameraRight = v; // Trying to change
                });
            }

object.shadowCameraLeft = v; // Trying to change
object.shadowCameraRight = v; // Trying to change
```

How do I change the size of shadowCamera ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pattern to follow to update the shadow camera on-the-fly:

```
light.shadow.camera.left = - 100;
light.shadow.camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); // important!
```

three.js r.73

Comment: it still does not change

Comment: This is the correct answer, and from your image, it looks to me like it did change, since the cube's shadows are clipped. I can't debug your code for you, I can only answer questions about three.js.

Comment: This seems to no longer work in r73. I'm trying to find out how to do it again after the update from r72 to r73. It works on initialization but I can no longer modify the shadow frustum afterwards.

Comment: @Spencer Updated answer.